# Replacing part of a query string with another value

Tags: c#

I have this url http://spdata.com?value=1&rem=288&data=1 ..I want to replace the rem=288(this 288 is not static ) with some other value like membership=1 .Can someone tell me how to do this.
Was thinking about doing a substring and then combining but not sure if there is an already easy process to do this .

Thanks

Comment: Are you building that url dynamically?  Or do you have a big chunk of text with many urls in them that you need to replace?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it with regular expressions.

Something like this:

```
using System.Text.RegularExpressions;
string newUrl= Regex.Replace("http://spdata.com?value=1&rem=288&data=1", @"rem=\d*", "membership=1",RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
```

Comment: Very nice and precise.

Comment: @Agustin Very Nice answer bro it Worth to be accepted answer and up vote :)

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you.According to your url pattern, this will change all `"rem=x"` with another value.In this case it is `"membership=1"`,ofcourse you can make it dynamic too.

```
var url = "http://spdata.com?value=1&rem=288&data=1";

var parts = url.Split('&').Select(x =>
        {
            if (x.Contains("rem=")) return "membership=1";
            return x;
        });

var result = string.Join("&", parts);
```

Answer (score 1):

Try To use This

```
   string text = "membership=1";
   string x = "http://spdata.com?value=1&rem=288&data=1 ";
   int y = x.IndexOf("rem=");

   string z = x.Substring(y, x.Length - y);

   int a = z.IndexOf("&");

   string url = x.Substring(0, y) + text + z.Substring(a, z.Length - a);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want easy, quick and readable then why not just concatenate the strings together? Or use string.Format

```
string key="rem";
string value="288";
string.Format("http://spdata.com?value=1&{0}={1}&data=1", key, value)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Uri uri = new Uri("http://spdata.com?value=1&rem=288&data=1...")
var pairs = HttpUtility.ParseQueryString(uri.Query)
pairs.Remove("rem");
pairs.Add("membership", "1");

var builder = new UriBuilder(uri);
builder.Query = pairs.ToString();

Uri modified = builder.Uri;
```